# Jquery ajax success, not working no return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I really need your help.
I got this problem in my jQuery, i try to make a ajax call to a Javascript there keep an array inside in this file.

test-ajax.js

```
    var data = ["kategori", "Alarm"];

return data;
```

But it come not with an array or anything not a single error. 
Here is the ajax call.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tip").mouseover( function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/kraftvaerk/falck/FalckAlarmWeb/FalckAlarmWeb.Website/js/test-ajax.js",
                dataType: "javascript",
                succes: function(resultat) {
                    console.log("here");
                    $(".tip").append("<span>Katagori: " + resultat[0] + " <br /> Beskrivelse: "+ resultat[1] +"</span>");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

In Html i got a table inside that table is there an a tag with class tip.
When the user mouse over that tag it should make the ajax call.

WARNING.
I use jQuery 1.2.2 the customer site i can´t upgrade it
Json is not ALLOW on thit project.

Comment: What does `http://localhost:8080/kraftvaerk/falck/FalckAlarmWeb/FalckAlarmWeb.Website/js/test-ajax.js` return?

Comment: There is  an additional `]` assuming typo

Comment: Try to show the error ? Does "here" appears in the JS console ?

Comment: `dataType:"javascript"` isn't an option. `script` is, but that returns the script as plain text. `resultat` won't contain the array you're trying to return from your script. You need to rethink what you're attempting here. Maybe a .json file instead of a script?

Comment: it call the file can i see in Chrome network console, but does reutn anything. 

that´s my when i post this in the file there i no extra ] so that can´t be the problem

Console does print any error´s

Comment: json can´t be used. It is a old system, with jQuery 1.2.2 @JasonP

Comment: You may need to parse it yourself, just get the data from the server and if JSON doesn't exist then use a json parsing javascript file.

Comment: you don't need jQuery to parse json. Your script as-is creates a global `data` var. You should instead simply have it contain the json and rename the file to .json or .txt, then parse the json in the success.

Comment: @JamesBlack 
That can´t be allow on this old system, and the backed-end team return not an json objeckt, as i order return there an Js array.

Comment: a js array IS valid json.

Comment: @user3173634 saying json isn't allowed doesn't make any sense. You're returning javascript, that contains an array. That array, with all the javascript around it removed, IS json. You CAN use json with jquery 1.2.2, you just have to do the parsing on your own (which isn't difficult.)

Comment: @KevinB but the system i am build to allow not Json, and that is not the original return

Comment: @user3173634 i created a demo but i can't share you let me post the code.

Comment: okay post the code and let me see it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21557498/1131841

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define and return a variable in your test-ajax.js file. You can simply define it as follows:

```
["kategori", "Alarm"]
```

Also, you had an extra bracket on the end that was invalid syntax.

Comment: That syntax it an post fail in the original file there an extra bracket.

But i tried it no return and no var defines but it still not working

But i can see in the networks tab in chrome it got at status 200 and  show `["kategori", "Alarm"]` 0: kategori 1: Alarm
So most be the success there is not working

Comment: @user3173634 did you remove the dataType when you did this test?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using is more similar to jsonp. jsonp works by including a script tag on your page that points to a js script that executes a function containing the data.

For example, your test-ajax.js would be:

```
testajax(["kategori", "Alarm"]);
```

and to request it, simply do this:

```
window.testajax = function(data) {
    console.log(data[0],data[1]);
};
$.getScript("test-ajax.js");
```

There you go. you just performed your first JSONP request, and it didn't involve any "json".

Answer (score 0):

i try to do the same like you but from $.ajax it is not returning the result but if you use the below example then you will get the result but your file should like this :

```
JScript1.js   ["kategori", "Alarm"]
JScript1.json   ["kategori", "Alarm"]

1. $.getJSON("JScript1.js", function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    });

2.  $.getJSON("JScript1.json", function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    });
```

result:

```
Array[2]
0: "kategori"
1: "Alarm"
length: 2
```

Comment: But that can stille not be allow the code up can´t be change it need to bee an ajax.

The original is.
on hover an ajax call makes to an .NET file there call to the database after data to Kategori and Alarm.

Json is not allow to this
And basic it .NET will return ["data", "data"]

This example an JS file with array ["data", "data"] there need to return the array data on hover

Comment: Then try this http://irahuldev.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-call-ashx-file-through-jquery.html

Comment: Try this http://irahuldev.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-call-c-function-using-json.html